# Define global defaults for all route methods with Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Is there any solution to define global defaults for all routes in a Symfony project? For example, I would like to use the `GET` method by default for all routes, to avoid routes matching ANY method if I forgot to use `methods={…}` in one of them.

Comment: You can probably hook into the route compilation process, but looks more trouble than is worth. I'd just `bin/console debug:routes | grep ANY` and fix.

Answer (score 0):

A less expensive alternative to define all routes with the GET method is to add it to the controller. Now all routes within this controller only allow GET calls unless another one is specified:

```
/**
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // only allows GET
    }

    /**
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request)
    {
        // allows GET and POST
    }
}
```